# Finding unknown source of data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, data-manipulation

I have a SQL Server database that is possibly being manipulated by a third party services, such as DTS or VB Script ran from different server.

How do I find out that it is so and how do I find the location of them?

Note: I know it is silly to ask this question as it should be documented etc but I suppose these things happen.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what information you want to capture, but for interactive investigation SQL Profiler will show you all connections to the server and you can run a [trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006.aspx) over a longer period if you want.

Depending on your situation, you could also look into the Windows event log or even use network tracing tools to gather more information. It really depends on the details of the connections and how much work you want or need to put into it.

Finally, if you're interested in data changes on specific tables, you could add auditing triggers that use functions like SYSTEM_USER or HOST_NAME to log information about each INSERT or UPDATE.